# How to useState to pass through an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of objects, each containing a unique id and video source:

```
const workouts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    video: video,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    video: video,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    video: video,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    video: video,
  },
];
```

I'm using Next.js and basically I would like to display a page with a video component, I would then like to the user to be able to onClick move to the next video.

How can I make it that the next video src is fed to the video component when they click a button? What I don't understand is how to dynamically move to the next video in the sequence.

After the last video, I would like the user to be able to restart the sequence again if they choose to.

Comment: Please also add your code for the video player, otherwise we don't know what you're stuck on. You could start by binding the `src` of the video to a state variable.

Comment: you could store/change current id in state, onClick change the id, on view use something like this `workouts.find(({id}) => current === id)`